# How to easy check if joystick plugged (by c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, input, joystick, directinput

**I need to write an easy function that only return bool answer.**

if there is joystick plugged in the computer - true,else - false.
how can i do this?

I have tried to write this code, but i only get the num of deviced that plug by usb to my computer, i need to know that this usb is joystick.

```
UINT pNum = 0;
RAWINPUTDEVICELIST* arr = new RAWINPUTDEVICELIST;
PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList = arr;
GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &pNum, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
std::cout << "Num entered: " << pNum << std::endl;
```

Comment: Post your code for what you have tried in _hard way_ would help you get an better answer.

Comment: I Didnt write any code, i don't know how to write that function.

Comment: Then read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, because your question might be flagged as low effort without any searches.

Comment: [Gamepad class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`joyGetPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757107(v=vs.85)) function to determine **whether a given joystick is physically attached to the system**. If the specified joystick is not connected, joyGetPos returns a JOYERR_UNPLUGGED error value.

The [`joyGetNumDevs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/joystickapi/nf-joystickapi-joygetnumdevs) function returns the number of joysticks supported by the current driver or zero if no driver is installed.